# Sort prequisites list in makefile

Tags: makefile

Is there a makefile way to get the list of prequisites (`$^`) alphabetically sorted?

i have a Makefile like:

```
some_pdfs = $(wildcard src/*.pdf)

big_pdf: ${some_pdfs}
    pdftk $^ cat ouput $<
```

the problem is that the source pdfs are in unsorted order, but i want them to be alphabetically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [sort](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions):

```
some_pdfs = $(sort $(wildcard src/*.pdf))
```

If you like, you can sort the list within the rule:

```
big_pdf: ${some_pdfs}
    pdftk $(sort $^) cat ouput $<
```

Comment: i took a look in the makefile manual and could not find it... maybe i looked in the wrong place... thank!

Comment: @reox: Did you follow the link, and search for "sort"?